# How do I get my Asp.net website to display information in English?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I display some auto formatted information, mostly dates, on an ASP.NET web page.

The dates, days of the week, and months all appear to be in French or Italian (I don't know either language, but I'm guessing it is one of those).

How do I tell my website we are in the U.S.A. and only speak Spanish here?

...oops! I meant English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow Microsoft's directions for setting the Current Culture for your application:

[HOW TO: Set Current Culture Programatically](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306162) (you're probably most interested in the application wide app.config option)

Comment: The link shows to add `<globalization uiCulture="es" culture="es-MX" />` to the **web.config** file - it's already in there! Could there be something that is overriding that value?

Answer (score 1):

When doing date formating (like with String.Format() or DateTime.ToString())and not specifying culture, you get it gets formatted with CultureInfo.CurrentCulture as selected culture.
AFAIR this gets set from servers regional settings, so you need either to:

1. Change servers regional settings to US
2. Set threads current culture programmatically
3. Explicitly define culture when calling formatting/conversion methods

[This page could help you](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx).

Comment: I hate using the Brute Force technique, but right now this is all that works.